# Write a recursive function that will write the prime factors of a user inputted number

Tags: c++

I have posted about recursion a few times and I now understand it, although this problem has been stuck with me for quite some time now. I am supposed to write a program with two functions:

**1.** a function that returns the lowest prime factor of a user inputted number

**2.** a recursive function that calls the first function and displays the other prime factors

I have figured out the first function, but I cant seem to understand how to write the second function, if you guys could provide solutions and your input that would be great! (I was also messing around in the second function, but I don't think it leads to anything important so ignore that code).

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int smallFactor(int);
int isPrime(int);

int main()
{
    int posInt;

    cout << "Enter one positive integer: ";
        cin >> posInt;
    cout << "The prime factors of " << posInt << " are ";

    int newInt;
    newInt = isPrime(posInt); // this is me messing around trying to see how my program should work together
    smallFactor(newInt); // this is me messing around trying to see how my program should work together

    return 0;
}

int smallFactor(int posInt)
{
    if (posInt % 2 == 0)
        return 2;

    for (int i = 3; i * i <= posInt; i += 2)
    {
        if (posInt % i == 0)
            return i;
    }

    return posInt;
}

int isPrime(int posInt)
{
    // honestly no clue what im doing in this function, was just messing around to get ideas
    cout << smallFactor(posInt) << " ";

    int newInt = posInt / smallFactor(posInt);

    return newInt;
}
```

Comment: Start with writing a function for #1; you don’t have it

Comment: @VladFeinstein I tested my function smallFactor() (which applies to #1) and it works as its designed to.

Comment: What is the program supposed to print when a prime number factors the inputted number multiple times (e.g. 16 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 or 50 = 2 * 5 * 5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the recursive function can be:

```
//posInt should greater than 1;
void OutputPrimeFactors(int posInt)
{
    if(posInt == 1)
        return;

    int k = smallFactor(posInt);
    cout << k;
    if(k < posInt)
    {
        cout << ", ";
        OutputPrimeFactors(posInt / k);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You print nothing for `OutputPrimeFactors(1)` though (as comment suggest BTW).

Comment: yes, because every integer has factor of 1, and 1 is not prime number, so 1 is not print.

Answer (score 1):

Any given number X can be in one of two situations:

1. It is prime. The lowest prime factor of X is X itself.
2. It is composite, which means `X = sp * rest`, where `sp` is the smallest prime that divides X. `rest` is then either prime or again a composite number.

Your recursive function should implement the above process.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive function might look like:

```
void printPrimeDecomposition(int posInt)
{
    const int s = smallFactor(posInt);

    if (s == posInt) { // is a prime
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << s << " ";
        printPrimeDecomposition(posInt / s);
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cb258bed05e8dce)